# get the url values from Firebase Realtime database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]
I have the above format in firebase realtime database
I need to get data in arraylist

```
public class EmojiView extends AppCompatActivity {


FirebaseUser firebaseUser;
DatabaseReference reference;

ArrayList<String> images = new ArrayList<>();

private void getImagesfromDB() {
    firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("stickers");
    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                String data = snapshot.getValue(String.class);
                images.add(data);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_emoji_view);
    getImagesfromDB();

}
}
```

I get the urls in data variable in OnDataChangemethod, but i am not able to assign those values to images arraylist

Comment: What is the problem with the arrayList? is it not being populated at all? is it being populated but with wrong data? you need to explaing what the problem is exactly.

Comment: I am not getting the data and also i want it to get assigned to ArrayList[] urls declaration

Comment: "I am not getting the data" How did you determine that? Note that we can't see anything beyond what you shared, so it's best if you make sure the information in your question very explicitly shows the output you get, and the output you expected. Also see [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: i updated the code

Comment: First of all, stop ignoring errors. Use `Log.d(TAG, error.getMessage());`. Do you get something printed out in the logcat? How did you check that?

Comment: does "data" have a value? check that

Comment: yes, data does has value.

Comment: Then what is the value, man?!  And why can't you just add it to an array???? why are you so stingy in sharing information? do you want help or not? :)))

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Change your reference to this:

```
reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("stickers").getChildren();
```

And then loop through the snapshots (which should be the children of "stickers") this way:

```
reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        
        for (DataSnapshot item : snapshot){
            stickers.add(item.getValue(String.class));
        }    

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

    }
});
```